# JQuery - ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

Some content...

Now I need to load some file into **inner**-block, but save it's old content.

```
$('#inner').load( 'pathToFile.html' );
```

Will replace old content of div.

Thanks.

---

So, as I understand my code should be:

```
old = $('#inner').html();
$('#inner').load( 'pathToFile.html' );
$('#inner').html( old + $('#inner').html() );
```

?

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to just save the old content but append to it. That's why you're getting different answers.

Comment: He means 'save the old content' as in 'leave it there', I assumed.

Comment: Very confusing as to what you are looking for with how you asked your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend against using stuff like 'load' and the other ajax helpers. They're just wrappers around [$.ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options). Off the top of my head, maybe you want:

```
$.ajax( {
  url: 'pathToFile.html',
  type: 'get',
  success: function( r ) {
    $('#inner').append( r );
  }
} );
```

Comment: What's wrong with using an ajax helper? I've used them myself with few problems.

Comment: The helpers are simply wrappers on $.ajax and they're light on features. Of course $.ajax _is_ a helper, what I mean is the ones that wrap it. For example, you can't have a failure handler with $.get. It's very little extra code to just use $.ajax, you can omit features you don't need, and it's clearer for everyone reading it. All IMO, of course :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the way you doing you need to look at these functions  ..

```
append( content )   Returns: jQuery
```

Append content to the inside of every matched element.

```
appendTo( selector )    Returns: jQuery
```

Append all of the matched elements to another, specified, set of elements. As of jQuery 1.3.2, returns all of the inserted elements.

```
prepend( content )  Returns: jQuery
```

Prepend content to the inside of every matched element.

```
prependTo( selector )   Returns: jQuery
```

and yes @thenduks method is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldHtml = $('#inner').html();
$('#inner').load( 'pathToFile.html' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var originalContent=$('#inner').html();
$('#inner').load( 'pathToFile.html' );
```

is that what you are after?